# Port open/closed checking in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Port checking from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758580/port-checking-from-php)

Anyone know best practice for this? I have an array of `("web"=>"10.4.54.65:443","ssh"=>"sunshine.local:22")` (about total of eight) and looking to find out how to get an array back with "web"=>"online|144ms" or something. 
All the guides I see are for sngle IP, multiple port and I'm not best at PHP.

Thanks

Comment: foreach() loop and how ever your checking for open\closed

Comment: loop over your list, attempt to connect to each ip/port in sequence. If the connection is refused, then the port's not open, or is firewalled.

Comment: looking at that @hakre but does this mean i have to have a ton of those if($!)'s? i don't know how to properly set up a foreach to write another array out with results

Answer (score 1):

"i don't know how to properly set up a foreach to write another array out with results"

```
$c=array("web"=>"10.4.54.65:443","ssh"=>"sunshine.local:22");


function check_function($ip){
//blah
return $result;
}
$out=array();
foreach($c as $k=>$v){
    $out[$k]=check_function($v);
}
print_r($out);
```